# Verb or adjective

Tags: verbs, adjectives, parts-of-speech, gre

*"If it weren't for the mitigating circumstances, he would have certainly lost his job."*

In the above sentence, what is the part of speech for the word "mitigating"?

I am preparing for the GRE and the Magoosh flashcard says that it is a verb but it looks like an adjective to me. Is this just a typo or am i missing something here?
Reference link:
https://gre.magoosh.com/flashcards/vocabulary/common-words-2/mitigate

Comment: It's a verb if you think *mitigate* is what the circumstance does. It's an adjective if you think of *mitigating circumstances* as a specified group of circumstances. If I had my druthers, I'd call it an adjective in this case.

Comment: It's probably an adjective, though some might analyse it as a verb, in which case it's a verb phrase in the same way that "sleeping" is in "a sleeping child".

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for your response. Do you have any sources I can refer to learn more about the same? My grammar needs some work.

Comment: Look here for the adjectival interpretation: [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mitigating)

Comment: @redd BillJ's Cambridge Dictionary link looks good. Here are some [general references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/142322) that the ELU community has put together, including a small section on grammar.

Comment: @Lawrence Have you a reference supporting the dual-analysis stance here, Lawrence? (I'd agree with what you say).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Mitigating* in *mitigating circumstances* is considered an adjective by BillJ's [Cambridge Dictionary link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mitigating) and a verb by ODO's definition 1.1, which supplies this example: [‘he would have faced a prison sentence but for mitigating circumstances’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mitigate).

Comment: I've combined my comments into an answer since there's now enough substance for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you consider to be the role of the word *mitigating* in the phrase *mitigating circumstances*.

It's a verb if you think *mitigate* is what the circumstance does. This is supported by Oxford Dictionaries (as [originally linked by BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380758/verb-or-adjective/380845#comment896107_380758)):

> **mitigate** *verb*
>   1.1 Lessen the gravity of (an offence or mistake)
>   ‘he would have faced a prison sentence but for mitigating circumstances’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mitigate)

It's an adjective if you think of *mitigating circumstances* as a particular group of circumstances. This is supported by Cambridge Dictionary:

> **mitigating** *adjective*
>   formal making something less harmful, unpleasant, or bad:
>   Are there any mitigating circumstances/factors that might help explain her appalling behaviour?
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mitigating)

To my ear, treating it as an adjective gives a more natural reading in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It is a present participle functioning in this context as an adjective.
And as *mitigating circumstances* has already established itself as a set phrase, it would then be safe to say, by way of logic, that it is an adjective.
Outside this expression, it might be either a present participle or an adjective, depending on the context.